# Angular resource, customize GET object

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular resource,

I'd like to extend any object returned by the factory with some computed properties from the object itself.

How can I add a post get step to the ngResource factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend the prototype like this:

```
angular.factory('Person', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  var Person = $resource(...);

  ...

  Person.prototype.computedProp = this.prop1 + this.prop2;

  return Person;

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested compatibility yet, but anyway I wanted to share how I did this to mantain Angular's style in my views code.

The idea is that the REST call gives me a distance in KM and a duration (in a format parseable by moment.js). What I wanted to achieve is computed property that would yield the average speed in KM/hour.

```js
.factory('Times', function ($resource) {
  var Times = $resource("api/users/:userid/times/:id", {});
  Times.prototype.__defineGetter__("average_speed", function () {
    return this.distance / moment.duration(this.duration).asHours();
  });
  return Times;
})
```